# Getting connection refused while reading file from hdfs using pyspark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

I installed hadoop 2.7, set the paths and set the configurations in core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml as follows:

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>

    <value>hdfs://<ip_addr>:9000/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>

    <value>/home/kavya/hdfs/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>

    <value>/home/kavya/hdfs/name</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>

    <value>hdfs://<ip_addr>:9000/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>

    <value>/home/kavya/hdfs/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>

    <value>/home/kavya/hdfs/name</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I also started the hdfs using start-dfs.sh. Inspite of mentioning the IP address in the configuration, I get connection refused error like:

```
Call From spark/<ip_addr> to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused
```

I stored file onto hdfs from my vm using:

```
hadoop fs -put /opt/TestLogs/traffic_log.log /usr/local/hadoop/TestLogs
```

This is a part of my code in pyspark to read file from hdfs and then extract the fields:

```
file = sc.textFile("hdfs://<ip_addr>/usr/local/hadoop/TestLogs/traffic_log.log")
result = file.filter(lambda x: len(x)>0)
result = result.map(lambda x: x.split("\n"))
print(result) # PythonRDD[2] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala

lines = result.map(func1).collect() #this is where I get the connection refused error.
print(lines)
```

`func1` is function containing regex expressions to extract the fields from my logs. And then the result is returned to `lines`. This program works perfectly fine when reading text file directly from vm.

> Spark version:spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
>   VM: CentOS

How to resolve this error? Am I missing out something?

Comment: Looks like you have installed hadoop on a linux machine. Couple of things. Have you implemented ssh correctly? Did you formatted your namenode and started all the services?

Comment: Yes ssh is working fine. I formated the namenode and started service using `start-dfs.sh`. But still getting connection refused error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be set:

1) In hdfs-site.xml make sure you have permissions disabled:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
<property>
```

2) In core-site.xml set your IP address to the IP address of the master:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://<MASTER IP ADDRESS>:8020</value>
<property>
```